# Windows 10 Recovery USB on Dell XPS 8910 Fails

Tags: windows-10, recovery

I have a Dell XPS 8910 with a HDD that seems like it is about to fail. I have backed up all files and created a recovery USB flash drive on a 16GB flash drive.

I am trying to "Recover from a drive" in the recovery options. When I disconnect the failing HDD and install a new SSD and try the recovery process with the USB it consistently fails at around 10% on the "Just remove my files" option and at about 90% on the "Fully clean the drive" option.  The specific error message is:

> “There was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made.”

I have tried two different USB flash drives and I am getting exactly the same result with each.

What troubleshooting options do I have at this point?

Comment: "What troubleshooting options do I have at this point?" - You should replace the drive. What you are doing is failing due to the failure of the hardware.

Comment: I have physically replaced the drive by connecting the new SSD and disconnected the old HDD.  I plug in the recovery disk and start up the computer.  I get options for "Recover from a drive" but those options fail with the message, "There was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made.".

Comment: You cannot reset your Windows installation if you have installed a new storage device

Answer (score 0):

Buy another SATA cable for old HDD , install SSD , Create new usb windows 10 installation USB using Microsoft USB tool and Windows 10 iso  (download from Microsoft) ,disconnect faulty drive , reinstall windows  on SSD .Reconnect HDD and manually copy files from  HDD drive (D:\Users\Nameofuser\ (all these files on old drive /mount point) into SSD(assume its drive c , so C:\Users\Newuser)